# ImportError: cannot import name random_integers

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

I've got Python code with a preamble containing the line:

```
from numpy import array,arccosh,random_integers
```

Later in the code I (successfully) use `array` and `arccosh`. However, I get an error in when the program is run:

```
from numpy import array,arccosh,random_integers
ImportError: cannot import name random_integers
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with NumPy, but a quick Google search tells me that `random_ingegers` is actually in `numpy.random`. So, `from numpy.random import random_integers`, maybe?